# Как работать с QEvent?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

Как работать с QEvent ??

Попробовал с основного потока следующему потоку информацию(QString) передать через класс наследованный от QEvent.

Стал делать по примеру в книге Макса Шлее (Qt5.3), Но там я даже не понял конструкцию

```
public:
    enum {ProgressType = User + 1};

    ProgressEvent() : QEvent((Type)ProgressType)
    {
    }
```

А когда я создал такую же у себя, она собралась, но не передала строку, ;_; грустно.

mainwindow.h

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>

#include <QCheckBox>
#include <QHBoxLayout>
#include <QDebug>

#include <QThread>
#include <QEvent>

#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>


namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

    int glob_i ;
    int glob_flow;
    int vector_schet; // датчик счёта

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();

public slots:
    void start_sending(bool); // принажатии на чекбокс то выполниться этот слот (отправка сообщений)


private slots:
    void on_pushButton_clicked();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;


    QThread *thread = new QThread();
    QVector<QThread*> vector_thread;

    QList<QCheckBox*> test_checkbox;  // вот вектор
    QCheckBox *checkBox = new QCheckBox();

    // Создаём виджет, который будет содержать в себе чекбокс
    QWidget *checkBoxWidget = new QWidget();
    // создаём слой с привязкой к виджету
    QHBoxLayout *layoutCheckBox = new QHBoxLayout(checkBoxWidget);
};

class NewsThread: public QThread
{
    Q_OBJECT
public slots:
    void run_NEW(); // код выполняемый в потоке

signals:
    void otprawka (int);
};


class StrokaEvent: public QEvent{

public:
    enum  {qwert = User + 1};
    StrokaEvent() : QEvent((Type)qwert)
    {
    }

    QString stroka;

    QString NewStroka();

    void setStroka(QString);
};
```

mainwindow.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    glob_i=0;
    glob_flow =0;
    vector_schet =0;
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    glob_i++;

    //-- добавляем чек бокс в таблицу
    checkBoxWidget = new QWidget();  // создаём новый qwidget()
    checkBox = new QCheckBox();      // объявляем и инициализируем чекбокс
    layoutCheckBox = new QHBoxLayout(checkBoxWidget); // создаём слой с привязкой к виджету
    test_checkbox.append(checkBox);
    int i =0;
    connect(checkBox, SIGNAL(toggled(bool)),this, SLOT(start_sending(bool))); // соединение всех чекетов с "действием"  start_sending

    checkBox->setText(QString::number(glob_i));

    layoutCheckBox->addWidget(checkBox);            // Устанавливаем чекбокс в слой

    layoutCheckBox->setAlignment(Qt::AlignCenter);  // Отцентровываем чекбокс
    layoutCheckBox->setContentsMargins(0,0,0,0);    // Устанавливаем нулевые отступы

    ui->tW_test->insertRow(ui->tW_test->rowCount());//вводим колич строк (возвращ колич строк)
    ui->tW_test->setCellWidget(ui->tW_test->rowCount()-1, 1,  checkBoxWidget); // добавляем элемент в таблицу (строка, столбец, добавляемый элемент)
}

void MainWindow::start_sending(bool Value)
{   
    // когда нажата отрабатывает, отжата то не отрабатывает
    if (Value == true)
    {
        NewsThread *two_cl = new NewsThread(); // инициализируем второй класс
        for (int i =0;i < test_checkbox.length();i++ )
        {
            if(test_checkbox[i]->isChecked() ==Value)
            {
                glob_flow++;

                QString strok = "dimasik :3";
                StrokaEvent *S_E = new StrokaEvent;
                S_E->setStroka(strok);

                connect(test_checkbox[i], SIGNAL(stateChanged(int)), two_cl , SLOT(run_NEW()));// от кого, "реакция", кому, "выполнение"

                thread = new QThread(); 
                vector_thread.append(thread);

                vector_schet++;
                qDebug() << "vector_schet : " << vector_schet ;
                two_cl->moveToThread(vector_thread[vector_schet-1]); // отправляем в поток

                vector_thread[vector_schet-1]->start(); // цикл обработки сообщения в потоке (второй поток)
            }
        }
    }
    else {
        qDebug() << "chekbocks:" << " False";
        glob_flow--;
        qDebug() << "vector_schet : " << vector_schet ;
        vector_thread[vector_schet-1]->exit();
    }
}

void NewsThread::run_NEW()
{
    StrokaEvent *S_E = new StrokaEvent;

    qDebug() << "run_NEW()";
    for(;;){ // вечный цикл
        for (int i=0; i<500; i++){
            qDebug()<< "Число :" << i <<"номер \"потока\" :" << S_E->NewStroka();
            usleep(100000);
        }
    }
}

QString StrokaEvent::NewStroka()
{
    return stroka;
}

void StrokaEvent::setStroka(QString str)
{
    stroka =  str;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для создания нового типа QEvent::Type лучше использовать статический метод QEvent::registerEventType(), чтоб не было повторов.

StrokaEvent нужно ловить в переопределенном виртуальном методе QObject::event.

Вы же создаете новый экземпляр и удивляетесь почему там пусто:

```
void NewsThread::run_NEW()
{ 
    StrokaEvent *S_E = new StrokaEvent;
    ...
    S_E->NewStroka()
}
```

Не знаю что там пишет Шлее, возможно Вы его не правильно поняли?
Вот пример использования QEvent для отправки сообщений между потоками:

stringEvent.h

```
#ifndef STRINGEVENT_H
#define STRINGEVENT_H

#include <QEvent>
#include <QString>

class StringEvent : public QEvent
{
public:
    StringEvent(const QString &_text);

    static QEvent::Type type();

    const QString &getText() const;

private:
    const QString text;

    static QEvent::Type m_eventType;
};

#endif // STRINGEVENT_H
```

stringEvent.cpp

```
#include "stringevent.h"

QEvent::Type StringEvent::m_eventType = QEvent::None;

StringEvent::StringEvent(const QString &_text):
    QEvent(StringEvent::type()),
    text(_text)
{

}

QEvent::Type StringEvent::type()
{
    if (m_eventType == QEvent::None)
    {
        int generatedType = QEvent::registerEventType();
        m_eventType = static_cast<QEvent::Type>(generatedType);
    }

    return m_eventType;
}

const QString &StringEvent::getText() const
{
    return text;
}
```

threadedclass.h

```
#ifndef THREADEDCLASS_H
#define THREADEDCLASS_H

#include <QThread>
#include <QDebug>
#include "stringevent.h"

class ThreadedClass : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    ThreadedClass(QObject *_parent = nullptr):
        QObject(_parent)
    {

    }

public:
    virtual bool event(QEvent *event) override
    {
        if(event->type() == StringEvent::type())
        {
            StringEvent *strEvent = static_cast<StringEvent*>(event);

            qDebug() << "Handle string | " << strEvent->getText() << " | from thread < " << QThread::currentThread();
        }

        return QObject::event(event);
    }   
};

#endif // THREADEDCLASS_H
```

MainWindow.h

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include "threadedclass.h"

namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~MainWindow();

private slots:
    void on_pushButton_clicked();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;

    ThreadedClass *m_thread;
    QThread *m_th1;
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

MainWindow.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include "stringevent.h"
#include <QDebug>


MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    m_thread = new ThreadedClass();

    m_th1 = new QThread();
    m_th1->start();

    m_thread->moveToThread(m_th1);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    const QString text = ui->lineEdit->text();

    qDebug() << "Try send text string from thread < " << QThread::currentThread();

    qApp->postEvent(m_thread, new StringEvent(text));
}
```

После запуска программы, вводы текста  в lineEdit  и нажатия кнопки - получаем вывод:

```
Try send text string from thread <  QThread(0x36db80)
Handle string |  "test1"  | from thread <  QThread(0x370938)
```

Comment: А в чём разница между этим способом и отправки сигнала и "ловле" его через connect?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3794649/qt-events-and-signal-slots

Comment: @Мишаков Максим, у вас в примере qApp не определен

Answer (score 1):

Вы не сделали главного, саму передачу сообщения. В Qt это делается двумя способами:

1. синхроно, с помощью функции `QCoreApplication::sendEvent()`, сообщение будет обработано получателем в теле `sendEvent()`; при этом если получатель в другом потоке, то поток отправителя будет приостановлен.
2. асинхронно, с помощью функции `QCoreApplication::postEvent()`, сообщение только добавиться в очередь к получателю, потоки не будет приостанавливаться.